# XML for Qemu `-nic user,model=virtio-net-pci` Network

Tags: libvirt

How do I specify a network interface in libvirt XML that is equivalent to the qemu-system-* argument `-nic user,model=virtio-net-pci`. I have a variety of qemu machines (without KVM) that happily boot with this argument but I can't figure out how to specify it in a domain XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this out by creating a domain with `virt-install` and `--network=user`. The resultant XML:

```xml
<interface type="user">
  <model type="virtio"/>
</interface>
```